# using R to make calculations across certain rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I’m a beginner with R and appreciate all the help on this website.  But I have been unable to locate a solution to a little problem...

I have 3 columns of data: SchoolName, Year, SATScore

There are many different school names, and for each school name, there is a “Year” which ranges from 2001-2012.  (ex., JFK high school has 12 years of SAT data).

**For each high school, I need to calculate the difference between SAT score in 2012 and SAT score in 2001.**

A pivot table in Excel does this in a few minutes, but I’d like to learn how to do it in R.

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on the format of your data. If it looks like this

```
dat <- structure(list(shool = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c"), year = c(2001L, 2004L, 2012L, 2001L, 2005L, 2012L, 2001L, 
2007L, 2012L), sat = c(12L, 45L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 44L, 55L, 5L
)), .Names = c("shool", "year", "sat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

>dat
#  shool year sat
#1     a 2001  12
#2     a 2004  45
#3     a 2012   5
#4     b 2001   6
#5     b 2005   8
#6     b 2012   9
#7     c 2001  44
#8     c 2007  55
#9     c 2012   5
```

Then you can simply do:

```
dat$sat[dat$year == 2012] - dat$sat[dat$year == 2001]
```

If things are not ordered so nicely, I suggest:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(dat, .(shool), summarise, 
      difference = sat[year == 2012] -  sat[year == 2001]   )

#      shool difference
#    1     a         -7
#    2     b          3
#    3     c        -39
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data is in a data frame called data. You can do the following:

```
data2001 <- data.frame(SchoolName = data[data$Year == 2001, ]$SchoolName, Score2001 = data[data$Year == 2001, ]$SATscore)
data2012 <- data.frame(SchoolName = data[data$Year == 2012, ]$SchoolName, Score2012 = data[data$Year == 2012, ]$SATscore)
stats <- merge(data2001, data2012)
stats$Difference <- stats$Score2012 - stats$Score2001
```

Comment: why not condense `data.frame(SchoolName = data[data$Year == 2001, ]$SchoolName, Score2001 = data[data$Year == 2001, ]$SATscore)` into `data[data$Year == 2001]` , you could throw away the year column after if you really want

Comment: I just wanted to have different names for Score columns in data2001 and data2012, so that I can merge them more easily.